# How to get two columns with having clause

Tags: sql

My data table is:

```
code
--------
ABCD0000
AAAA0000
BBBB0000
CCCC0000
DDDD0001
```

Say I want find list of code that have same ends numbers is equal to 4,
It should return

```
substring|substring
---------|--------- 
ABCD      0000
AAAA      0000
BBBB      0000
CCCC      0000
```

my sql codes is

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(subjects.code ,5, 8), SUBSTRING(subjects.code ,1, 4)
FROM subjects
HAVING count(SUBSTRING(subjects.code ,5, 8)) = 8;
```

Its raises error as

> column "subjects.code" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

But if I added it in the query, it returns nothing

Comment: Add `GROUP BY` clause before `HAVING` with same columns as `SELECT`.

Comment: It still return nothing, substring | substring 
-----------+-----------
(0 rows)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1f08ec2ba6754c245213c014f5010fe3)):

Create and populate your table:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects
(
  code VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO subjects VALUES ('ABCD0000'), ('AAAA0000'), ('BBBB0000'), ('CCCC0000'), ('DDDD0001');
```

Then run **preliminary** SQL:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING (code, 5, 8) AS codes4, 
  COUNT(SUBSTRING (code, 5, 8)) AS cnt
FROM subjects
GROUP BY codes4
HAVING  COUNT(SUBSTRING (code, 5, 8)) = 4
```

Result:

```
codes4  cnt
  0000    4
```

Then `JOIN` this result back to your original table:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING (code, 1, 4) AS prefix,
  SUBSTRING (code, 5, 8) AS codes4
FROM subjects s
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUBSTRING (code, 5, 8) AS codes4, COUNT(SUBSTRING (code, 5, 8)) AS cnt
  FROM subjects
  GROUP BY codes4
  HAVING  COUNT(SUBSTRING (code, 5, 8)) = 4
) AS t 
ON SUBSTRING(s.code, 5, 8) = t.codes4;
```

Result:

```
prefix  codes4
  ABCD    0000
  AAAA    0000
  BBBB    0000
  CCCC    0000
```

Et voilà! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you RDBMS supports window functions, you can do this without joining. Just do a window count in a subquery, then filter in the outer query:

```
select prefix, code
from (
    select
        substring (code, 1, 4) prefix,
        substring (code, 5, 8) code,
        count(*) over(partition by substring(code, 5, 8)) cnt
    from mytable
) t
where cnt = 4
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3f3a3ec370d837259c12a1030bca3145)**:

```
prefix | code
:----- | :---
ABCD   | 0000
AAAA   | 0000
BBBB   | 0000
CCCC   | 0000
```

Answer (score 0):

use [CTE](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/)

```
;with cte as
(
    Select SUBSTRING(code ,5, 8) as substring1, SUBSTRING(code ,1, 4) as substring2 from subjects
)
SELECT * FROM cte group by substring1,substring2 having COUNT(substring1)=8;
```